# JPA criteria produce a query with just a one question point

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria

In our data base we have the cache system, what is sensitive for query binding parameters.

I have the following query creation:

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Position> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    query.distinct(true);
    final Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    Join<Position, ManagersPositions> managersPositionsJoin = root.join("managersPositions", JoinType.INNER);

    Predicate managerPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(managersPositionsJoin.get("managerId"), managerId);
    predicates.add(managerPredicate);

    if (onlyDirect) {
        Predicate equalsDirect = criteriaBuilder.equal(managersPositionsJoin.get("isDirect"), true);
        predicates.add(equalsDirect);
    }
    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
}
```

And it produce the following query:

```
select
   distinct position0_.id as id1_69_0_,
   ...
where managerspo1_.manager_id=22
and managerspo1_.is_direct=?
```

I have to send the request with 2 binding parameters like:

```
where managerspo1_.manager_id=?
and managerspo1_.is_direct=?
```

How can I solve the problem with the first "?"?

Comment: Why don't you use `criteriaBuilder.parameter()`?

Comment: ```criteriaBuilder.parameter()``` with criteriaBuilder.equal(..., parameter) has the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't fount a workaround of my problem and my decision is "hand-create" the query with entity manager without specification.

```
final String queryString = "select distinct pos from Position pos " +
            "inner join pos.managersPositions mn " +
            "where mn.managerId = :managerId and mn.isDirect = :isDirect ";

    TypedQuery<Position> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            queryString,
            Position.class);
    query.setParameter("managerId", managerEmployeeId);
    query.setParameter("isDirect", true);
```

Because when i made the `criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));` it makes just a one predicate with a one parameter.

Also tried to divide specification into 2 and result was unsuccessfull:

```
Specification.where(firstSpecification).and(secondSpecification)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CriteriaBuilder.parameter() to add multiple parameters:

```
    ParameterExpression<Integer> managerIdParam = 
        criteriaBuilder.parameter( Integer.class );
    ParameterExpression<Boolean> isDirectParam = 
        criteriaBuilder.parameter( Boolean.class );
    Predicate managerPredicate = 
        criteriaBuilder.equal(managersPositionsJoin.get("managerId"), 
        managerIdParam);
    Predicate equalsDirect = 
        criteriaBuilder.equal(managersPositionsJoin.get("isDirect"), isDirectParam);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.